# Override org.joda.time.LocalDate with org.gwttime.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, gwt, jodatime

I'm trying to develop a generic module that is independent of GWT until it is actually used in a GWT application. The problem is that GWT does not support joda and my module does not use GWT.

What I'm trying to achieve (this will not work):

```
<replace-with class="org.gwttime.time.LocalDate">
    <when-type-is class="org.joda.time.LocalDate" />
</replace-with>
```

Last resort would be to add custom parsing and some smart rules at runtime, but I would like to avoid that and solve this problem at compile time.

Is there any way to easily specify the gwttime as emulation for the joda time?

Comment: why not using code generation + annotations ? http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/annotation-generators/

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, it might be useful in the future. It looks a bit daunting and for now I found I can use the simpler GWT override option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the `<super-source> .gwt.xml` directive.

I checked out the gwttime project, renamed all the package and imports declarations from `org.gwttime.time` to `org.joda.time` then added an `Emulation.gwt.xml` to the parent source folder where the gwttime files were located with the following content:

```
<module>
   <super-source/>
</module>
```

Then the package structure was identical to `org.joda.time`.

This way I can use the same imports on the client and on the server side and the replacement will happen at compile-time.